# How does electric current flow in daniell cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

The actual question in my mind is that ……..at anode zinc oxidises to form $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ and $2$ electrons, but it should be the same case at cathode because copper should also oxidise to form $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ and $2$ electrons. Then in this case the potential difference is zero hence there is no current flow……please clarify?

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: The Daniell cell is such a frequent topic on many sites involved in chemistry, including this one, that I have strong suspicion you have not done your searching homework before asking.

Comment: I have done it already but i coulnt find it

Comment: To search this site: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=daniell+cell A sample of results: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/175183/simple-cell-vs-daniell-cell Look up also definition of cathode and anode.

Comment: I closed and then quickly reopened when I saw that my [proposed duplicate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/160276/what-happens-with-electric-charges-in-a-salt-water-battery?rq=1) is about a salt water cell with a different electrolyte. Similar principles hold though.

Comment: This is closer to what you are asking: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126644/copper-electrode-in-a-daniel-cell

Comment: You may find useful reviewing of search results for 
[site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu  Daniell Cell schema](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alibretexts.org+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Awikipedia.org+OR+site%3Ahyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu+Daniell+Cell+schema)

Answer (score 0):

Physics student is wrong for two reasons. First, in the Daniell cell cathode, copper is not oxidized. It is the contrary. It is reduced from $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ to $\ce{Cu}$, and it is reduced by the $2$ electrons produced by zinc at the anode. Second, the potential difference is not zero. It depends on the concentration of the ions in solution. But it is usually around $1$ Volt.

Comment: The copper electrode is at a different potential from the zinc electrode. Also is the Daniell cell not designed to give a well defined voltage  and its use restricted to a Wheatstone bridge environment of ZERO current draw, hence a constant voltage. This could be where the confusion is arising.